# How to make flushleft work on multicolumn title?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, multicolumn

In the below code, "Title3Title3 Title3Title3 Title3Title3" is misaligned with the other titles because flushleft does not seem to work with multicolumn titles. How do I left-justify all of these text titles?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{html,makeidx,color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\pagecolor{white}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.1in} \setlength{\textwidth}{6.1in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.1in} \setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.8in}
%\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{harvard}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}

\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist 

\begin{document}

\title{ Test Title}
\author{}
\maketitle

\begin{table}[htb]\centering \caption{Caption1 }
\scalebox{0.95}{
\begin{tabular}{l   p{2cm} p{2cm} p{2cm} p{2cm}  p{2cm}}\hline\hline
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textit{Uber Title 1 Uber Title 1 }} & \textit{Uber Title 2 Uber Title 2 }\\ \\ \hline
& \textit{\begin{flushleft} $ 100\%$ Title1Title1  \end{flushleft}}& \textit{\begin{flushleft} Title2 Title2 Title 2 \mbox{industries} \end{flushleft} } &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{  Title3Title3 Title3Title3 Title3Title3  }} & \textit{\begin{flushleft} Title4 Title4 \end{flushleft}}\\ \hline
 & \textit{taxation 1 Taxation 1 } 
& \textit{Taxation2 Taxation2 (Dummy values; Actual Numbers TBD) }  & \textit{Taxation3 Taxation3}& \textit{Taxation4}  & \textit{Taxation5} \\ \hline
\textbf{XYZ} & & &  & & \\ \hline
- Percentage of Metric X$^1$ & 0.35 &  0.42 &  0.46 & 0.60 &  0.72  \\ 
- per ton shipped metric$^2$ & \$ 43.32 & \$ 52.00 & \$ 56.91 & \$ 73.82 & \$ 86.16  \\ 
\\\\ \hline
\textbf{PQR} & & &  & \\ \hline
RV$^3$(2014\$ Billions) & -\$ 2156.94 & -\$ 2427.89 & -\$ 2522.36 & -\$ 2983.78 & -\$ 4698.51  \\ 
- percentage of XYZ & -0.24 &  -0.27 & -0.28 & -0.33 &  -0.54  \\ 
- per Dollar of XYZ$^4$ & -\$ 0.50 & -\$ 0.64 & -\$ 0.66 & -\$ 0.79 & -\$ 0.81  \\ 
- per TON shipped $^3$ & -\$ 26.01 & -\$ 29.28 & -\$ 30.42 & -\$ 35.99 & -\$ 46.19  \\ 
Reductions in XYZ & 29.98 \% &  29.98 \% &  29.98 \% & 29.98 \% &  37.02 \% \\

\hline
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{enumerate}[$^1$]
%\item [\text{Note:}]
\item Footnote1
\item Footnote2
\item Footnote3
\end{enumerate}

\end{table}
```

\end{document}

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your document isn't complete at all!

Comment: you know it's kind of depressing to put work into making a document look reasonable only to see the same thing posted a few minutes later back as it was.

Comment: i'm going to assume you meant to end that example with `\end{document}` but at any rate, is this really a minimal working example?  or just a working example...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sincere apologies David, I frankly didn't know your answer on the other question solves this one as well, I am very new to Latex. I literally opened LateX on my computer 2 days back, and have been editing a large TEX file that I got from someone else with dozens of similar looking tables. I really appreciate your quick and useful reply on the other thread - thanks for that. And please don't feel bad about this question, I genuinely felt it was a different problem altogether.

Comment: It is a slightly different problem. but it's nice to see documents improve not go backwards:-) But do multicolumn titles as in the comment I left under my last answer but change `@{}c@{}` to `@{}l@{}` if you want them flush left

Comment: unrelated to your question but `[ansinew]` is a rather odd choice of encoding for a document this millennium. Why not a standard encoding such as utf8 or latin1?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i'd wager the op didn't put `[ansinew]` in their on their own, it's probably a really old document that they're editing.

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer but I can't stick this in a comment.  And if David's comment fixed your problem, feel free to ignore the rest of this.

I'm not sure what exactly you're asking, and I understand you're editing a document that's already been made.  Conceptually, can you clarify what you'd like to align?  Do you want Title3Title3 to align with Uber Title 1 or Title 2 or Taxation3?  Right now you have specified for it to be centered over two columns.  Is that the only part of the table you want to align differently?

Or are you trying to make titles for a hierarchical table like this?

[image: hierarchicalTable]

(produced by this:)

```
\documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{fullpage}
    %for top, mid, and bottom rule:
    \usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l*7c}
    \toprule[1.5pt]
      & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{First Group} &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Second Group} &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Third Group} \\
          \cmidrule(r){3-4}                  \cmidrule(r){5-6}                   \cmidrule(r){7-8}
    Label & No Group & Thing 1 & Thing 2 & Thing 1 & Thing 2 & Thing 1 & Thing 2 \\
    \midrule
    row name & ungrouped & numbers & numbers & numbers & numbers & numbers & numbers \\
    \bottomrule[1.25pt]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```